# Crossplatform Plugin architecture with MAUI

Tags: android, .net, maui, plugin-architecture

My goal is to create app on Android/Windows using MAUI, and as I want to be able to add to this app more functionality by plugins, I want to create some simple plugin system.
This plugins should be able to subscribe to domain events, add components (like menu items and "pages" components that will be shown in app after menu click), communicate with each other.
So, is there any way to do it cross-platform?
If it was only windows, I would just create plugins dlls, on app start up I need to load them, find every `IPlugin` or similar, initialize them, etc.
But where to store it on Android? How to compile/load this plugins on Android? (and in future not only Android, but iOS & Mac too)

P.S. I'm super new to MAUI stuff, and need to learn a lot, so appreciate full answers
P.P.S. Not a native English speaker, sorry for mistakes

Comment: Not sure if you seen: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

Comment: I need to integrate code and controls that potentially will be out of project. Your link is about 'how to create cross-platform code'. My question is about 'how to compile library' and 'how to load it on different platforms'